# get Teacher Superannuation age in sql query

Tags: sql, date

Thanks in advance : please help me out wirting a sql query to find the supperannuation date of of an employee  i have to get all those employee wich are going to be 60 years in age on different dates  so i need to get those dates from date of birth .

```
TeacherName         DateOfBirth          TeacherAge     SupperannuationDate(onwhich teacher going to be 60 yers)
-------------------------------------------------------
S. KHALID SALIM 1958-03-23 00:00:00.000  55
ZUBAIDA BEGUM   1976-08-01 00:00:00.000  36
TANZEEM AKHTAR  1974-09-25 00:00:00.000  38
MARYAM BIBI     1982-08-18 00:00:00.000  30
RABIA TABASSUM  1976-11-10 00:00:00.000   36
```

---

here is my query i need a fourth column with name "AnnunationDate " on which a teacher age will be 60 year .

```
select  TeacherName ,DateOfBirth , datediff(mm, DateOfBirth, getdate()) / 12 as TeacherAge  from Teachers
```

------------------------For example at first row it will display in fourth column
 1963-03-23 00:00:00.000 somthing

Comment: what is your dbms by the way ?

Answer (score 0):

SQL server

```
SELECT
TeacherName,
dateadd(year, 60 , DateOfBirth) as superannuationDate
FROM Teachers
```

Mysql

```
SELECT
TeacherName,
DATE_ADD(DateOfBirth, INTERVAL 60 YEAR) as superannuationDate
FROM Teachers
```

Oracle

```
SELECT
TeacherName,
ADD_YEARS(DateOfBirth, 60) as superannuationDate
FROM Teachers
```